# Flutter Dart Model how to write an generic modal class

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a dart model using the tool and below is the model

```
class Questions {
  List<Question> mathematics;
  List<Question> physics;

  Questions({this.mathematics, this.physics});

  Questions.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['Mathematics'] != null) {
      mathematics = new List<Question>();
      json['Mathematics'].forEach((v) {
        mathematics.add(new Question.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['Physics'] != null) {
      physics = new List<Question>();
      json['Physics'].forEach((v) {
        physics.add(new Question.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.mathematics != null) {
      data['Mathematics'] = this.mathematics.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.physics != null) {
      data['Physics'] = this.physics.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Question {
  int questionId;
  int questionPaperId;
  int serialNumber;
  bool multiSelect;
  String subject;
  String image;

  Question(
      {this.questionId,
        this.questionPaperId,
        this.serialNumber,
        this.multiSelect,
        this.subject,
        this.image});

  Question.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    questionId = json['questionId'];
    questionPaperId = json['questionPaperId'];
    serialNumber = json['serialNumber'];
    multiSelect = json['multiSelect'];
    subject = json['subject'];
    image = json['image'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['questionId'] = this.questionId;
    data['questionPaperId'] = this.questionPaperId;
    data['serialNumber'] = this.serialNumber;
    data['multiSelect'] = this.multiSelect;
    data['subject'] = this.subject;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    return data;
  }
}
```

But these subjects are just a simple set i can have any subject. Like i can have a subject like Chemistry Computer Biology.

I am looking for a generalized way of writing the model. Like instead individual list i want something like a map of these. Like in my case a map with below key and value
"mathematics" : List
"physics" : List

How do i generalize the dart model?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Questions {
  var subjects = <String, List<Question>>{};

  Questions.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    json.keys.forEach((matter) {
      subjects[matter] = (json[matter] as List).map<Question>((e) => Question.fromJson(e));
    });
  }
}
```

I'm supposing `json[matter]` is a *List*, you can change it. Without raw data, it's difficult to know if this code works 100%.